# persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml not working correctly together

Tags: hibernate, jpa, properties, configuration, persistence

This is my current project structure:

```
pom.xml
/src
  /main
    /resources
      hibernate.cfg.xml
      /META-INF
        persistence.xml
```

***I still need to add a hibernate.properties*** to get hibernate properties working. Example:

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

***The same property is not getting activated with hibernate.cfg.xml***

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

***How can I get arround this? Should I use one file?***

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the whole hibernate.cfg.xml file...

Comment: "persistence.xml" is there to include ALL properties